# String to C array/struct in Qt

Tags: c, arrays, string, qt, struct

I have a log file which contains logged data and a report. In my Qt project, I need to parse the log file and collect the data and report. The collected data will then be assigned to a C array and structure. This seems to be complicated for me due to lack experience in Qt String class. Could anybody guide me some reference code or document?

Below is an example of the log file content.

```
***************************FrameCounter: 138
Data Begin
/*       0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11 */
/* 0*/   0,    0,   -1,    0,    1,   -2,    4,    0,   -1,    4,    0,   -5, 
/* 1*/   1,   -1,    6,    2,    2,    0,    1,   -3,   -2,    3,    0,   -2, 
/* 2*/   1,    1,    5,    2,    4,    2,    1,    5,   -1,   -2,   -2,   -4, 
/* 3*/   1,  -16,  -46,  -87,  -99,  -48,   -5,    6,    4,  -10,    1,    1, 
/* 4*/  21,   -2,   -1,   -3,  -27,  -12,   -3,    8,   -1,   -5,   -4,    1, 
/* 5*/  66,  213,  120,   38,   -1,   -9,  -10,   -7,  -15,  -13,   -4,    1, 
/* 6*/ 308, 1847,  921,   32,   -1,   -2,  -45,  -88, -102,  -76,   -3,    1, 
/* 7*/ 137, 1263,  674,   31,   -8,   -1,  -24,  -58,  -87,  -77,  -15,    1, 
/* 8*/   5,   39,   42,   25,  -17,    1,   -1,  -26,  -35,  -42,  -19,    0, 
/* 9*/  -7,  -10,    4,   -2,  -24,    2,   44,   53,    7,   -2,  -10,   -7, 
/*10*/ -35,  -78,  -97,  -58,  -57,    1,  672, 1250,  150,  -21,  -31,  -27, 
/*11*/ -37, -122, -127, -132,    0,    4,  972, 1659,  224,  -24,  -13,  -27, 
/*12*/  -1,  -14,  -14,  -28,  -28,   30,   80,  150,   53,   18,  -19,  -32, 
/*13*/  -1,   34,  738,  516,  -22,   13,    1,   -6,  152,  120,   -1,  -25, 
/*14*/ -15,  118, 1761, 1137,   35,    1,  -87,  -55, 1593, 1082,   -1,  -22, 
/*15*/   1,    2,  341,  229,   15,    1,  -27,   -5,  839,  685,    4,    0, 
/*16*/   4,    1,   -1,  -21,  -32,  -19,  -13,  -15,   27,    2,  -34,   -3, 
/*17*/   2,   -1,  -19,  -62,  -81,  -49,   -7,   -1,   -1,  -43,  -46,   -1, 
/*18*/   1,   13,    5,  -18,  -57,  -49,  -13,    3,   11,  -19,  -37,   -3, 
/*19*/   4,   12,   18,   -1,  -32,  -33,   -1,   11,   16,    8,    1,    3, 
/*20*/   0,    5,   18,    3,  -13,  -16,    1,   11,   14,    9,    5,    1, 
/*21*/   2,   13,   26,   12,    2,   -3,    3,    8,   15,    7,    3,    1, 
Data End

Report Begin
TouchNum = 4
Unit[0].x = 109
Unit[0].y = 148
Unit[0].Flag = 0
Unit[0].Id = 0
Unit[0].z = 255
Unit[0].Type = 152
Unit[1].x = 452
Unit[1].y = 242
Unit[1].Flag = 0
Unit[1].Id = 3
Unit[1].z = 255
Unit[1].Type = 152
Unit[2].x = 179
Unit[2].y = 313
Unit[2].Flag = 0
Unit[2].Id = 2
Unit[2].z = 255
Unit[2].Type = 152
Unit[3].x = 557
Unit[3].y = 322
Unit[3].Flag = 0
Unit[3].Id = 1
Unit[3].z = 255
Unit[3].Type = 152
Report End
```

Comment: Formalize first the possible inputs (perhaps thru some BNF grammar). Then code a parser for it.

Comment: Might be best to stick with QByteArray, if you're putting it to C string anyway. Remember, QString is unicode characters, and should not be thought of as bytes or a C char string.